# Python row-locking without WeakValueDictionary

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to prevent concurrent access to a dictionary on a per-element basis. Specifically, I have a `Cache` class:

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
    def query(self, item):
        try:
            return self._values[item]
        except KeyError:
            value = compute_value(item) # Expensive operation
            self._values[item] = value
            return value
```

In words, `Cache` should compute item values on demand, then cache them for later queries.

`Cache` is used from multiple threads. I want to avoid threads concurrently calling `compute_value(...)` for the same `item`: If threads `A` and `B` both request the value for `my_item`, then only `A` should compute it. `B` should wait for its result, then use the cached value.

I've implemented this as follows:

```
from threading import Lock
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self._locks = WeakValueDictionary()
    def query(self, item):
        with self._locks.setdefault(item, Lock()):
            try:
                return self._values[item]
            except KeyError:
                value = compute_value(item)
                self._values[item] = value
                return value
```

This works. In particular, my use of `WeakValueDictionary` ensures that concurrent queries to the same `item` get the same `Lock`, but that the locks don't stay around in memory forever.

The problem is that my application actually creates many instances of `Cache` on the fly. Because of this, the call `self._values = WeakValueDictionary()` becomes a performance bottleneck.

I am looking for a solution that lets me achieve the same task, but with normal Python dictionary instead of `WeakValueDictionary`. I tried:

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self._locks = {} # No more WeakValueDictionary
    def query(self, item):
        with self._locks.setdefault(item, Lock()):
            # as before...
        del self._locks[item]
```

But this did not fully prevent concurrent access. Specifically, if threads `A` and `B` obtain the same lock and `A` deletes it while `B` still holds it, then another thread `C` can come along and get a *new* lock for the same row and thus access it at the same time as `B`.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be achieved, maybe with other primitives such as semaphores?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really imagine a way of automatic synchronization, so I would use a *master lock* to protect locks accesses, and a count of pending requests. The item lock should only be deleted when no other request is pending (count == 0). Code is larger but it should be bullet proof:

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self._locks = {}
        self._master_lock = Lock()
    def query(self, item):
        with self._master_lock:
            if item in self._values:         # if value is ready return it immediately
                return self._values[item]
            lock = self._locks.setdefault(   # else build or use an item lock
                item, [Lock(), 0])           # and say we are pending on it
            lock[1] += 1
        with lock[0]:                        # release master lock and acquire item one
            exc = None                       # be prepared to any exception
            try:                             # read or compute (first time only) the value
                val = self._values.setdefault(
                    item, compute_value(item))
            except Exception as e:
                exc = e                      # note the exception for later re-raise
        with self._master_lock:              # release item lock and take again master one
            lock[1] -= 1                     # we are no longer pending
            if lock[1] == 0:                 # if no other thread is either
                del self._locks[item]        # delete the item lock
        if exc:
            raise exc                        # eventually re-raise
        return val
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you confirm that the performance bottleneck is `self._values = WeakValueDictionary()`? It doesn't make sense. And I did a profile:

```
%timeit locks = WeakValueDictionary()

2.52 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As you can see, it only costs `2.52 µs` per loop. You need to create millions of `Cache` object to cost just two seconds.

As far as I think, your performance bottleneck should come from `with self._locks.setdefault(item, Lock()):` as it will create new `Lock` object for every concurrent queries.

Actually there is one thing I cannot understand fully, why you need to delete `Lock` object after query? Couldn't every `key` have a corresponding `Lock` permanently? And when you delete this `key`, you can also delete its `Lock`.

Comment: I used cProfile to find out that instantiating 30,000 `WeakValueDictionary`s takes ~100ms on my machine. That's in line with your measurements. And it's too much for my use case. Creating `Lock`s is cheaper, and not the dominating cost (again, in my environment).

Comment: I am deleting the `Lock` object to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Well, creating `Lock` is cheaper but is also much more frequent. In my environment, creating `WeakValueDictionary` is just 20 times more expensive than creating `Lock`. But since you have said that... whatever. About memory leaks, I don't think it is a problem as all locks will be distoried with `Cache` itself.